# Tab sequencing with JRadioButton

Tags: java, spring, swing, jradiobutton

I am developing GUI in an application (which is based on Spring framework) using Swing. In one of the screens, we have several JButtons, JLabels, JFormattedtextFields and JRadioButtons in a panel. 
The question is:

1). When I press the tab button from the keyboard, the control does not goe to the JRadioButton field (though it goes to other components before and after it). It does not appear on these radio buttons (a serious issue with the application). How to fix this.

2).Also to set the text(label) for each radio buton, i have to do in separate labels:

```
<label text="Raiding" constraints="21,1" font="Arial-PLAIN-12" />
    <buttongroup>
    <radiobutton id="raidingYesID"  font="Arial-PLAIN-12"
                    opaque="false" constraints="22,1" label="Yes"/>
    <label text="Yes" constraints="23,1" font="Arial-PLAIN-12" />                   
    <radiobutton id="raidingNOID" font="Arial-PLAIN-12"
                   selected="true" opaque="true" constraints="24,1"/>            
    <label text="No" constraints="25,1" font="Arial-PLAIN-12" />   
    </buttongroup>
```

I tried to do it in java, but the labels did not appear:

```
raidingYesID.setLabel("Yes");
raidingYesID.setName("Yes");
raidingNOID.setText("No");
```

none of them made any difference, but i could get the label on console by using:

```
System.out.println(raidingYesID.getLabel());
```

do suggest any solutions...

Comment: take first question on priority...

Comment: looks like a tag is missing - the ui is created by loading a xml?

Comment: also, I would suggest you read the api doc instead of randomly calling methods and hope for the best. Plus never-ever use deprecated methods.

Comment: a) why do you mix labels into a buttongroup? b) the radiobutton with id "raidingNOID" has no text attribute c) why the different opaqueness properties to the two radiobuttons?

Comment: hey kleopatra, thanks for your concern and yes we are using xml along with POJOs for UI.

Comment: label was required to set the text for the radio button, as no oher way worked out in this context

Comment: there's something completely wrong ... the text _must_ appear on the button itself (the label only stands in the way, f.i. the radiobutton doesn't appear focused). As long as you can't make that work, you're stuck -I'm aware that this comment isn't overly helpful, as you noticed that yourself, but make it nevertheless: you _must_ figure out how to make the text appear: throw out everything else - just one radiobutton with a text attribute, no backend nor binding nor label nor buttongroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question: use `setText()` to set the `JRadioButton` text and use `getText()` to get it back. The button text can also be set in the constructor.

Comment: it worked after increasing the gui's xml attribute: <layout type="FormLayout" columns=" 50dlu,13dlu,2dlu,15dlu,7dlu, 13dlu,2dlu,15dlu,7dlu,15dlu, 2dlu,15dlu,55dlu,70dlu,15dlu, 15dlu,15dlu,15dlu,15dlu,50dlu,25dlu,30dlu, 35dlu,10dlu"> actually it was not able to appear since it had less pixels(or dlus) previously assined.

Comment: also by setting the attribute text="Yes" in radiobutton: <radiobutton id="raidingYesID"  font="Arial-PLAIN-12"
                    opaque="false" constraints="22,1" text="Yes"/>